# Is there a more efficient way of writing this code?

Tags: java, minecraft

I'm making a sort of "hack" or "mod" for Minecraft. It'll delete the blocks around you, and move forward, delete more, move forward, etc. After a certain amount of time it'll move to the side and head back. It's like the world is slowly deleting itself :D

```
if(Camb.nuker){
    whenToStop++;
    byte byte0 = 3;
    if(whenToStop < 60){
        mc.thePlayer.setPosition(posX, posY, posZ-1.5);
    }
    if(whenToStop > 60 && whenToStop < 65){
        mc.thePlayer.setPosition(posX-1.2, posY, posZ);
    }
    if(whenToStop > 65 && whenToStop < 124){
        mc.thePlayer.setPosition(posX, posY, posZ+1.5);
    }
    if(whenToStop > 124 && whenToStop < 129){
        mc.thePlayer.setPosition(posX-1.2, posY, posZ);
    }
    if(whenToStop > 129 && whenToStop < 188){
        mc.thePlayer.setPosition(posX, posY, posZ-1.5);
    }
    if(whenToStop > 188 && whenToStop < 193){
        mc.thePlayer.setPosition(posX-1.2, posY, posZ);
    }
    if(whenToStop > 193 && whenToStop < 252){
        mc.thePlayer.setPosition(posX, posY, posZ+1.5);
    }
    if(whenToStop > 252 && whenToStop < 257){
        mc.thePlayer.setPosition(posX-1.2, posY, posZ);
    }
    if(whenToStop > 257 && whenToStop < 316){
        mc.thePlayer.setPosition(posX, posY, posZ-1.5);
    }
    if(whenToStop > 316 && whenToStop < 321){
        mc.thePlayer.setPosition(posX-1.2, posY, posZ);
    }
    if(whenToStop > 321 && whenToStop < 376){
        mc.thePlayer.setPosition(posX, posY, posZ+1.5);
    }

    for(int k = byte0; k > -byte0; k--)
    {
        for(int i1 = byte0; i1 > -byte0; i1--)
        {
            for(int j1 = byte0; j1 > -byte0; j1--)
            {
                double d1 = mc.thePlayer.posX + (double)k;
                double d3 = mc.thePlayer.posY + (double)i1;
                double d5 = mc.thePlayer.posZ + (double)j1;
                int k1 = (int)d1;
                int l1 = (int)d3;
                int i2 = (int)d5;
                int j2 = mc.theWorld.getBlockId(k1, l1, i2);
                Block block = Block.blocksList[j2];
                if(block != null){
                    ((EntityClientPlayerMP)mc.thePlayer).sendQueue.addToSendQueue(new Packet14BlockDig(0, k1, l1, i2, 1));
                    ((EntityClientPlayerMP)mc.thePlayer).sendQueue.addToSendQueue(new Packet14BlockDig(2, k1, l1, i2, 1));   
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
if(Camb.nuker==false){
    whenToStop = 0;
}
```

You mainly have to focus on the chunk of code under where I declare the byte. The rest of the code is looping through the blocks and breaking them, nothing too special.

So how would I make that chunk of code more efficient? I'm thinking about making a function, but I'm not too knowledgable about making functions, how would I do something like that? For example, I would use the code *functionname*(number of rows to break);

Thanks,
Brad

Comment: `void functionname(int numberOfRowsToBreak) {/*implementation*/}`

Comment: Instead of multiple `if`, you should use `if(condition) {} else if(condition){}`

Comment: @gparyani Would I just paste all the if's into that? Thanks!

Comment: You could put the stops in a list/map and automate the responses with x/y/z deltas...

Comment: Also, never compare a boolean directly with `false`. Instead, use the not (`!`) operator in front of the boolean.

Comment: @gparyani Is there a difference, or a performance thing? I'll fix it.

By the way, how would I go about making this function anyway... it doesn't seem to work exactly as if I used the non-efficient method. Could I please have an example?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to move the player when whenToStop == 60, for example?

Comment: @JouniAro I'm a little confused... what do you mean?

Comment: "but I'm not too knowledgable about making functions" Being able to break your code down into functions is an absolute must; your code will start to get very unreadable and unmaintainable otherwise.

Comment: You'll also need either to change `>` to `>=` or to change `<` to `<=`

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about code *review*. Please ask your question at http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: I mean the same as Adam. It also looks like you could use the modulus operator (whenToStop % 128) or something like that, since you have a repeating pattern of four sections: moving -Z, moving -X, moving +Z, moving -X.

Comment: Trust me there are hundreds of things to be done with the code, not just this code, but any code, every one will try to imagine it the way he wishes to do it

Comment: @gparyani do you have any reference for that? It can even be slower if a JUMP IF FALSE opcode does not exist.

Comment: I don't really understand why this has so many votes ? Am i missing something ?

Answer (score 5):

First hit on the if block could be something like:

```
double dx = 0, dy = 0, dz = 0;
whenToStop++;
if (whenToStop < 60) {
  dz = -1.5;
} else if (whenToStop < 65) {
  dx = -1.2;
} else if (whenToStop < 124) {
  dz = +1.5;
} else if (whenToStop < 129) {
  dx = -1.2;
} else if (whenToStop < 188) {
  dz = -1.5;
} else if (whenToStop < 193) {
  dx = -1.2;
} else if (whenToStop < 252) {
  dz = +1.5;
} else if (whenToStop < 257) {
  dx = -1.2;
} else if (whenToStop < 316) {
  dz = -1.5;
} else if (whenToStop < 321) {
  dx = -1.2;
} else if (whenToStop < 376) {
  dz = +1.5;
}
setPosition(posX + dx, posY + dy, posZ + dz);
```

but that raises the question *what happens when the value is exactly equal to say 60*? Is that effect intentional?

Now it is in this form you should be able to use some form of array for the split points.

```
class D {
  final int p;
  final double x;
  final double y;
  final double z;

  public D(int p, double x, double y, double z) {
    this.p = p;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.z = z;
  }
}

D[] d = {
  new D(60,     0,   0, -1.5),
  new D(65,  -1.2,   0,    0),
  new D(124,    0,   0, +1.5),
  new D(129, -1.2,   0,    0),
  new D(188,    0,   0, -1.5),
  new D(193, -1.2,   0,    0),
  new D(252,    0,   0, +1.5),
  new D(257, -1.2,   0,    0),
  new D(316,    0,   0, -1.5),
  new D(321, -1.2,   0,    0),
  new D(376,    0,   0, +1.5),
};

...
  whenToStop++;
  D delta = null;
  for ( int i = 0; i < d.length && whenToStop < d[i].p; i++ ) {
    delta = d[i];
  }
  if ( delta != null ) {
    setPosition(posX + delta.x, posY + delta.y, posZ + delta.z);
  }
```

I'd say now you are where you need to be.

Comment: I liked your old version better, it was much clearer. Not everything needs to be an object.

Comment: @mavroprovato - me too - but the fundamentalists would demand the second form and you have to admit, the pattern is clearer.

Answer (score 1):

I'll elaborate on @MadProgrammer's suggestion:

Create a structure to hold the limit and deltas for each condition:

```
class Entry {
  int upper_limit;
  double delta_x;
  double delta_y;
  double delta_z;
}
```

Then fill a List of structures with the data:

```
ArrayList<Entry> entries;
entries.add(new Entry(60, 0., 0., -1.5));
entries.add(new Entry(65, -1.2, 0., 0.));
// Continue with the remaining entries.
```

Then pass the List to a function:

```
DoMove(List<Entry> entries, int when_to_stop, SomeClass mc,
       double pos_x, double pos_y, double pos_z) {

  for (Entry entry : entries) {
    if (when_to_stop < entry.upper_limit) {
      // move
    }
  }
 //  Default case or error
}
```

Comment: This is java, we don't have structs here :-)

Comment: I'd personally prefer using an enum over a class

Comment: Oops. (Guess what language I haven't used for a while!)  Thanks for the catch ... feel free to edit the syntax further.

Answer (score 0):

My modified version of OldCurmudgeons code. Make it a complete function (I assume the player is of PlayerType):

```
void move(PlayerType player, int step) {
    double dx = 0, dy = 0, dz = 0;
    int cycle = step % 128;
    if (cycle < 60) {
      dz = -1.5;
    } else if (cycle < 64) {
      dx = -1.2;
    } else if (cycle < 124) {
      dz = +1.5;
    } else {
      dx = -1.2;
    } 
    player.setPosition(player.posX + dx, player.posY + dy, player.posZ + dz);

}
```

And then your "main program" would call it like:

```
final int LIMIT = 1000; // this will stop the movement

if (Camb.nuker) {
   move(mc.thePlayer, step++);
   <your for loop>
   if (step == LIMIT)
     Camb.nuker = false;
} else
  step = 0;
```

Now you can use this indefinetely with as big values for whenToStop as you like.

I also think you had slight errors in the indexes, so I have straightened it to the 64/128 cycle.

Edit: no need for "if" on the final block.

Edit2: made it a function and "main program"

Edit3: whenToStop is a parameter to the function, no++ for it inside the function needed.

Edit4: 'int' missing before cycle declaration.

Edit5: 'player.' missing from the 'pos':s

Edit6: renamed variables and added a LIMIT

Comment: I think I'll try out you're code for now. I'm a little confused though. For example, how would I make it "break rows" twice? Or four times? Thanks

Comment: Hmm, I am not quite sure what you mean: do you mean, you would like to go through the same positions several times?

Comment: Yes, exactly. The way it works is it'll break the blocks in a huge row, move to the side, turn around and break again.

Comment: OK, you are confused with the '%' I think. It will "break" your whenToStop to a cycle of 128. Your whenToStop will keep on growing, but you want to repeat the same movements every 128 steps. So when whenToStop = 128 or 256, cycle = 0 again. If you just increase whenToStop, it will keep on repeating the movement, -z, -x, +z, -x, etc.

Comment: Ok. I'm getting "void is an invalid type for the variable movePlayer"

How do I fix this :O

Comment: Sorry, nooby mistake. Scratch that.

Comment: I'm a little confused though. How would I make it so it only breaks x blocks...

Comment: Do you mean how you limit whenToStop? You need to set Camb.nuker=false, when whenToStop is big enough.

Comment: Added a LIMIT to end the movement

Answer (score 0):

Loop can be rewritten as:

```
public void checkBytes(byte byte0) {
    double d1e = mc.thePlayer.posX - byte0;
    double d3e = mc.thePlayer.posY - byte0;
    double d5e = mc.thePlayer.posZ - byte0;
    for(double d1 = mc.thePlayer.posX + byte0; d1 > d1e; d1 -= 1.0) {
        for(double d3 = mc.thePlayer.posY + byte0; d3 > d3e; d3 -= 1.0) {
          for(double d1 = mc.thePlayer.posZ + byte0; d5 > d5e; d5 -= 1.0) {
                int k1 = (int)d1;
                int l1 = (int)d3;
                int i2 = (int)d5;
                int j2 = mc.theWorld.getBlockId(k1, l1, i2);
                Block block = Block.blocksList[j2];
                if(block != null){
                   ((EntityClientPlayerMP)mc.thePlayer).sendQueue.addToSendQueue(new Packet14BlockDig(0, k1, l1, i2, 1));
                   ((EntityClientPlayerMP)mc.thePlayer).sendQueue.addToSendQueue(new Packet14BlockDig(2, k1, l1, i2, 1));
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

This will save time for conversion double <->int, and twice decrease number of adding: instead of pair "k--" and "d1 = mc.thePlayer.posX + k" -- there will be just "d1 -= 1.0".

Also, if values d1/d3/d5 always positive (I not sure about this), you can define these values as ints, and remove casting to k1/l1/i2.

Answer (score -1):

in case you dont know, several if(){} makes the compiler check them in a reverse order, it checks the last if then the if before it then the one before it then so on

unlike if(){}else if(){}

if else makes the compiler check them in the written order, the first one in the code is the first one checked

any way, this is a some kind of reformatted code

```
// in your Camb class if possible
//...
private boolean nuker = false;
// more code that changes the nuker variable
public static boolean isNuker(){
    return nuker;
}


// in this class
if(Camb.isNuker()){
        whenToStop++;
        byte byte0 = 3;
        checkWhenToStop(whenToStop)
        checkBytes(byte0)
}else{
    whenToStop = 0;
}

public void checkWhenToStop(int whenToStop){
    if(whenToStop < 60){
        mc.thePlayer.setPosition(posX, posY, posZ-1.5);
    }
    if(whenToStop > 60 && whenToStop < 65){
        mc.thePlayer.setPosition(posX-1.2, posY, posZ);
    }
    if(whenToStop > 65 && whenToStop < 124){
        mc.thePlayer.setPosition(posX, posY, posZ+1.5);
    }
    if(whenToStop > 124 && whenToStop < 129){
        mc.thePlayer.setPosition(posX-1.2, posY, posZ);
    }
    if(whenToStop > 129 && whenToStop < 188){
        mc.thePlayer.setPosition(posX, posY, posZ-1.5);
    }
    if(whenToStop > 188 && whenToStop < 193){
        mc.thePlayer.setPosition(posX-1.2, posY, posZ);
    }
    if(whenToStop > 193 && whenToStop < 252){
        mc.thePlayer.setPosition(posX, posY, posZ+1.5);
    }
    if(whenToStop > 252 && whenToStop < 257){
        mc.thePlayer.setPosition(posX-1.2, posY, posZ);
    }
    if(whenToStop > 257 && whenToStop < 316){
        mc.thePlayer.setPosition(posX, posY, posZ-1.5);
    }
    if(whenToStop > 316 && whenToStop < 321){
        mc.thePlayer.setPosition(posX-1.2, posY, posZ);
    }
    if(whenToStop > 321 && whenToStop < 376){
        mc.thePlayer.setPosition(posX, posY, posZ+1.5);
    }
}

public void checkBytes(byte byte0){
        for(int k = byte0; k > -byte0; k--){
            for(int i1 = byte0; i1 > -byte0; i1--){
                for(int j1 = byte0; j1 > -byte0; j1--){
                    double d1 = mc.thePlayer.posX + (double)k;
                    double d3 = mc.thePlayer.posY + (double)i1;
                    double d5 = mc.thePlayer.posZ + (double)j1;
                    int k1 = (int)d1;
                    int l1 = (int)d3;
                    int i2 = (int)d5;
                    int j2 = mc.theWorld.getBlockId(k1, l1, i2);
                    Block block = Block.blocksList[j2];
                    if(block != null){
                       ((EntityClientPlayerMP)mc.thePlayer).sendQueue.addToSendQueue(new Packet14BlockDig(0, k1, l1, i2, 1));
                       ((EntityClientPlayerMP)mc.thePlayer).sendQueue.addToSendQueue(new Packet14BlockDig(2, k1, l1, i2, 1));
                    }
                }
            }

        }
}
```

Comment: you can even make your methods return a boolean value (true or false) in case you want to stop in the middle

Comment: Wouldn't you want to make it an `if(){}elseif(){}elseif(){}...` since they would never match more than one and therefor the application would not check each condition unnecessarily but only up to the one that applies.

Comment: I would rename checkWhenToStop to move().

Comment: Plus there are a few `whenToStop` ints that are unaccounted for such as `60, 65, 124, etc...`

Comment: Also I would write it like "cycle = whenToStop % 128; if (cycle < 60) move(-1.2, 0, 0); else if (cycle < 64) move(0,0,1.5) else if (cycle < 123) move(-1.2,0,1.5) else move(0,0,-1.5);" or something like that (I suspect the original indexes in the if statements are not correct either, so a cycle of 128 would be a better one.

Comment: @J.Romero ofcourse the if/else idea is much better, i just tried to make the code more clear with less modifications, i even mentioned the if/else in my first lines of my answer